# typing effect in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I try to copy-paste the typing text script from codepen to vue file but somehow it only blink and did not change nor show any word, it only show Im A' than blink block,i believe the script didn't run,does applying js in vue different than html?? if so teach me how to apply it please

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Im A'<span class="typed-text"></span><span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </div>

<style>
p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container p span.typed-text {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px yellow;
}
.container p span.cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
  width: 3px;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
.container p span.cursor.typing {
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0%  { background-color: #ccc; }
  49% { background-color: #ccc; }
  50% { background-color: transparent; }
  99% { background-color: transparent; }
  100%  { background-color: #ccc; }
}
</style>

<script>
const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");
    const cursorSpan = document.querySelector(".cursor");
    
    const textArray = ["web developer", "UI/UX Designer", "Front End"];
    const typingDelay = 200;
    const erasingDelay = 100;
    const newTextDelay = 2000; // Delay between current and next text
    let textArrayIndex = 0;
    let charIndex = 0;
    
    function type() {
      if (charIndex < textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
        if(!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
        typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
        charIndex++;
        setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
      } 
      else {
        cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
          setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
      }
    }
    
    function erase() {
        if (charIndex > 0) {
        if(!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
        typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex-1);
        charIndex--;
        setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
      } 
      else {
        cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
        textArrayIndex++;
        if(textArrayIndex>=textArray.length) textArrayIndex=0;
        setTimeout(type, typingDelay + 1100);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at following snippet:

```js
const { ref, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const textArray = ref(["web developer", "UI/UX Designer", "Front End"]);
    const typingDelay = ref(200);
    const erasingDelay = ref(100);
    const newTextDelay = ref(2000); // Delay between current and next text
    let textArrayIndex = ref(0);
    let charIndex = ref(0);
    const typedTextSpan = ref(0);
    const cursorSpan = ref(0);
    function type() {
      if (charIndex.value < textArray.value[textArrayIndex.value].length) {
        if(!cursorSpan.value.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.value.classList.add("typing");
        typedTextSpan.value.textContent += textArray.value[textArrayIndex.value].charAt(charIndex.value);
        charIndex.value++;
        setTimeout(() => type(), typingDelay.value);
      } 
      else {
        cursorSpan.value.classList.remove("typing");
        setTimeout(() => erase(), newTextDelay.value);
      }
    }

    function erase() {
      if (charIndex.value > 0) {
        if(!cursorSpan.value.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.value.classList.add("typing");
        typedTextSpan.value.textContent = textArray.value[textArrayIndex.value].substring(0, charIndex.value - 1);
        charIndex.value--;
        setTimeout(() => erase(), erasingDelay.value);
      } 
      else {
        cursorSpan.value.classList.remove("typing");
        textArrayIndex.value++;
        if(textArrayIndex.value >= textArray.value.length) textArrayIndex.value = 0;
        setTimeout(() => type(), typingDelay.value + 1100);
      }
    }
    onMounted(() => setTimeout(() => type(), 1000))
    return {
      typedTextSpan, cursorSpan
    }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container p span.typed-text {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px red;
}
.container p span.cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
  width: 3px;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
.container p span.cursor.typing {
  animation: none;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0%  { background-color: #ccc; }
  49% { background-color: #ccc; }
  50% { background-color: transparent; }
  99% { background-color: transparent; }
  100%  { background-color: #ccc; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Im A'<span ref="typedTextSpan" class="typed-text"></span><span ref="cursorSpan" class="cursor">&nbsp;</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way so i dont need to edit the script ser?and just straight copy paste any js code

Comment: @adityamms hey mate , if you want to do the same script functionality in Vue way than you need to change it

Comment: What if i put the code in the html would it crash or would it work the same?